# vb.net - call a backgroundworkers runworkerasync method from bw's name as a variable

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, listof

I have an app that's doing lots of time checks and looping through datatables etc checking for certain values at certain times etc.

The end result is that I have a list(of string) that contains the names of the "schedules" that need running at a particular time. Those names correspond to the names of a set of background workers.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can loop through that list and, using the backgroundworker name which is a string variable, call the corresponding background workers RunWorkerAsync method?

The background workers are already declared before runtime, and their names are static - matched by the names in the list.

I've been looking at the CallByName function, but cant find any usage examples of documentation that show it used in this way, so i'm not sure if I'm heading down a dead end there.

```
 For Each schedule In run_these_schedules
 CallByName(schedule, BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync)
 Next
```

Any help appreciated in advanced!

Comment: Probably, but you need to show some code. Are the backgroundworkers declared in your code as variables whose names are the strings in your list? If so are they class level properties or local Dims? Need to see it in code

Comment: Yeah but how are the actual backgroundworkers defined?

Comment: Thanks djv - I've updated my question and will continue to do so. The background workers are already declared and are class level. :)

Comment: Are the `schedule` in each of those run_these_schedules the names of backgroundworkers, or names of their corresponding methods?

Comment: @djv -They are added in design as an object. This app is a .net windows service, so they are the only object in design.

Comment: the schedule is the name of the background worker

Answer (score 4):

In the designer they will be declared by default as

```vb
Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker2 As ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
' ...
```

Looks like a field, however [once WithEvents gets added this is a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966746/832052)

So we can use Reflection and get the properties by name

```vb
Dim run_these_schedules As New List(Of String) From {"BackgroundWorker1", "BackgroundWorker2"}
For Each schedule In run_these_schedules
    Dim t = GetType(Service1)
    Dim pi = t.GetProperty(schedule,
                           Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or
                           Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or
                           Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    Dim bw = DirectCast(pi.GetValue(Me), BackgroundWorker)
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending djv's excellent answer, you could search the form for all backgroundworkers in the `Load()` event and store them in a `Dictionary(Of String, BackgroundWorker)` for fast lookup:

```
Private BWs As New Dictionary(Of String, BackgroundWorker)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each pi As Reflection.PropertyInfo In Me.GetType.GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim obj As Object = pi.GetValue(Me)
        If TypeOf (obj) Is BackgroundWorker Then
            Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(obj, BackgroundWorker)
            BWs.Add(pi.Name, bw)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim run_these_schedules() As String = {"BackgroundWorker1", "BackgroundWorker2", "UnicornsExist"}
    For Each schedule In run_these_schedules
        If BWs.ContainsKey(schedule) Then
            BWs(schedule).RunWorkerAsync()
        Else
            Debug.Print("Schedule not found: " & schedule)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, frontloads the Reflection for faster execution